# Sum only the numbers in String - Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

i have a label and it has number, dollar symbol and i have a UIStepper that increase and decrease the number. the problem that i face is that it cannot sum the number with the dollar symbol and what i want is to sum the number with the dollar symbol.

```
import UIKit
import GMStepper

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet var stepper: GMStepper!
@IBOutlet var priceLabel: UILabel!
var price: Double = 5.500


override func viewDidLoad() {
    
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    priceLabel.text = "5.5 $"
    
}


@IBAction func stepper(_ sender: Any) {
    
    let newValue =  price * stepper.value
    let priceS = String(format: "%.3f", newValue)
    priceLabel.text = "\(priceS) $"

   }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to sum up?  Where is that code?

Comment: What do you mean by sum?  Add up all the different digits, or just extract the value from the string?

Comment: You should use a [NumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter) for presentation and (ideally) [Decimal](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/decimal) numbers for calculations.

Comment: @Claudio Why would OP parse a number if there is already a price variable? OP should just increase the value or create another variable

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, just extract the value or to sum up the individual digits in the string.  So, to extract the digits (using `text` as the string you want to parse):

```
let value = Double(text.filter{"0123456789.".contains($0)})
```

Casting to Double will give an optional, so you'll need to handle that appropriately for your situation.  If it's coming from the stepper you might be able to safely force unwrap.

If you want to sum up the digits, you can use a similar approach:

````
let sum = text.filter{"0123456789".contains($0)}.reduce(0){$0 + Int(String($1))!}```
````

Comment: No, don't extract the value from string. Keep the value as number and only convert to `String` to display it. This is just silly. Also, you can parse number with currency using `NumberFormatter`.

Comment: @sulthan I think you are misreading the question. The source of the data as I read it is a string from a label.  Given how heavy weight all the formatter classes are I’d not instantiate one for something this simple.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's convert currency value to a `String` correctly.

The second thing is to forget about trying to use the `String` for anything. Consider formatted strings to be display-only. Don't try to convert them to numbers. Instead, keep the necessary value as a number.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
   private lazy var formatter: NumberFormatter = {
       let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
       numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
       numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
       numberFormatter.currencyCode = "USD"
       numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 3
       numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 3

       return numberFormatter
   }()

   var originalPrice: Double = 5.5
   private var price = originalPrice

   private func updateText() {
      priceLabel.text = formatter.string(for: price)
   }

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad();

      updateText()
   }

   @IBAction func stepper(_ sender: Any) { 
      // do any calculation here using price and stepper.value
      price = originalPrice * stepper.value
      updateText()
   }
}
```